# Issue in populating data in read only mode

Tags: docusignapi

I am using powerform to display the DocuSign to get the signature from users. There are few custom fields where I was populating data in read only mode in Demo env. Somehow the data in readonly mode stopped appearning since yesterday.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for using DocuSign! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a Powerform. Read-only fields with default text are shown (read-only) in the signing ceremony for the Powerform.

I agree that read only fields with no default text do not show on the document when it is shown in the signing ceremony. But why should they if they don't have default text?

How were you setting the read-only fields? Were you using the Powerform URL? If so, then signers could very easily change the "read only" values themselves by changing the URL themselves.

If this is the case, then the upgrade may be considered by the product group to be the "closing of a loophole."

If, on the other hand, you had a secure method for setting Powerform field values in a truly read-only pattern, then updates to the Powerform system may have missed this issue as a regression test.

Or were you setting the value of the read only field in the template itself? I just tried that and it worked fine: the field, with its read-only text, is shown in the document.

Please EDIT / UPDATE your question to describe how you are setting the values to be read-only.